# Computer automatically shuts off before even getting to the Welcome screen (WIndows Vista)

Tags: windows-vista

It only gets to the part where it gives you the option to "Start windows normally" or "Launch startup repair". If I select either option, it only shows a screen that says "Microsoft Windows" at the bottom center, with a little green bar. And then the computer automatically shuts off. What could be causing this? I haven't been able to get to the Welcome screen for several days.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Vista X64 boot freeze on loading splash](http://superuser.com/questions/6924/windows-vista-x64-boot-freeze-on-loading-splash)

Comment: You could be getting a BSOD without realizing it; make sure the BIOS option "Disable automatic restart on system failure" is selected

Answer (score 0):

You could have a CPU heat issue.  They will shut off if overheating.  check that the fans are operating